# empty MySQL concatenated join causes query failure

Tags: mysql, join

I am having trouble with a MySQL query (version 5.6.37). I think it merely needs a reorganizing of the query components, but I can not make it work.

Problem: when my JOIN returns no rows, the entire query returns no rows, even though the data matches the query.

Here is my current query (where '@' is the input):

```
SELECT pets.id,pet,collar,GROUP_CONCAT(petData.fleas) AS f_id
FROM titles 
    JOIN petWear    ON pets.id    = petWear 
    JOIN petData    ON petWear.id = petData.id 
WHERE pets.id = '@'
GROUP BY pets.id,pet,collar
```

Assuming a "pets" table like this:

```
id | pet
1  | cat
2  | dog
3  | fish
4  | snake
5  | rabbit
```

And a JOINed "petData" table like this:

```
id | fleas
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 3
1  | 4
2  | 5
```

Successful query:
If @ = 1, then the query returns a single result:

```
id | pet | collar | f_id
1  | cat | gold   | 1,2,3,4
```

Unsuccessful query:
If @ = 5, then the query returns no result.

What I would like to have returned (for @ = 5) is this single result (i.e. no result, or NULL, for "f_id"):

```
id | pet    | collar | f_id
5  | rabbit | red    |
```

Note that I have included the petWear table with the "collar" listing, just to state that a "normal" join needs to also be part of the picture.

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT OUTER JOIN petData`?

Comment: Also, thank you for the clear explanation of what you're trying to do!

Comment: Thank you, Bill and Jovi. I don't use SQL every day, and pointing me to the different JOIN *types* got me re-reading parts of the manual I haven't read in 15 years!  Changing `JOIN petData ` to `LEFT JOIN petData` was all I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Basically, if GROUP_CONCAT returns no values, it will print no_fleas

```
SELECT pets.id,pet,collar,IFNULL((GROUP_CONCAT(petData.fleas), 'no_fleas') AS f_id
FROM titles 
JOIN petWear    ON pets.id    = petWear 
JOIN petData    ON petWear.id = petData.id 
WHERE pets.id = '@'
GROUP BY pets.id,pet,collar
```

Comment: Thanks, Sami. I was looking for something like this. Unfortunately, it did not work in MySQL v. 5.6.37. I used the above recommendation to employ LEFT JOIN.